# Sudo keeps asking for password on / mounted over NFS

Tags: ubuntu, nfs, sudo

I have a diskless server booting Ubuntu 14.04 with `/` taken from NFS. I use `nfs-kernel-server`. I have some strange behaviour of `sudo` and `locate`.

- `sudo` keeps asking for passwords despite the `Defaults    timestamp_timeout=5` in the `sudoers`.
- `locate` does not update its db and does not find anything at all.

I suppose this is because of some misconfiguration of NFS? When I use this `/` on a usual machine both commands work as expected.

Here's my `/etc/exports` (I don't know what can I give more):

```
/noderoot   *(rw,no_root_squash,async,insecure,no_subtree_check)
```

Any advice?

Comment: can you add fsid=0 to the export? I know it shouldn't matter as you do not export on top of your root, but I have observed some strange behaviour in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it. The problem was not about NFS.

1. sudo kept asking me for passwords because I had wrong time on the diskless server. I set the time to the correct value and sudo worked.
2. locate did not update db because there were `PRUNEFS="nfs NFS nfs4 ..."` in the `/etc/cron.daily/locate` file. I removed nfs from `PRUNEFS` and it worked.